# Can log in user on Postman, but not on browser

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redux, react-final-form

If I can log in a user to Postman, then that means its my front end code that has a bug. Right?

CastError: Cast to string failed for value "{ email: 'admin@mail.com', password: '123456' }" (type Object) at path "email" for model "User"

It seems that path "email" is both taking in the email and password into one input. Is the problem in my front end or back end? I am using `react-final-form`

Reducer:

```
export const userLoginReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case USER_LOGIN_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true };
    case USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, userInfo: action.payload };
    case USER_LOGIN_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
    case USER_LOGOUT:
      return {};
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Action:

```
export const login = (email, password) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOGIN_REQUEST,
    });

    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };

    const { data } = await axios.post(
      "/api/users/login",
      { email, password },
      config
    );

    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });

    localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(data));
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOGIN_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    });
    toast.error("Invalid Credentials");
  }
};
```

Store

```
import {
  userLoginReducer,
} from "./reducers/userReducers";

const reducer = combineReducers({
  userLogin: userLoginReducer,
});

const userInfoFromStorage = localStorage.getItem("userInfo")
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userInfo"))
  : null;

const initialState = { userLogin: { userInfo: userInfoFromStorage } };
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your keys (email and password) in strings?

Comment: I have not, how would one wrap keys in strings?

Comment: If you apply JSON.stringify to your data in the  post to your server (so JSON.stringify(email), JSON.Stringify(password) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error, I suspect the error is due to your request body potentially not being a string.

I'd try updating your post to be the following:

```
    const { data } = await axios.post(
      "/api/users/login",
      { JSON.stringify(email), JSON.stringify(password) },
      config
    );
```

Which will ensure your request is passed to the server as a string

Comment: You're correct, that was the answer except I use   JSON.stringify(email, password),